# how do i turn on USB mass storage with a samsung galaxy note5 so i can transfer files

Tags: android, windows, debugging, usb, storage

I have searched a lot of places on Google and I just can't seem to figure out how to get my computer (which is running Windows 10) to recognize my phone so I can use it for programming. I was hoping someone can help me. It used to be simple before Android version 6.0.1 so I'm not sure if I am just not finding the right setting or what, so please if you have specific instructions or a site I can go to to help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Like I said before, all I am trying to do is somehow get my computer to recognize my phone so I can transfer files. It **used** to be that all I had to do was turn on USB mass storage but I can no longer find that option.

Comment: USB mass storage won't work at all because android 6.x+ uses ext4 as filesystem. Windows does not support ext4. Thats why android uses PTP or MTP for file transfers over USB.

Comment: The only down side of this is you are not able to acess folder that don't have a  photo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specifically about programming, but about general usage of this device (transferring files). You may get better help on [Android Enthusiasts StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Well first  You need to make sure You have to install your drivers 
Second thing Plug in your Phone in when click in notification tray see if you can find an option saying "Photo transfer" if you connect to that maybe your device will get recognized.
**That worked for me on my nexus 5x on 6.0.1**

If transering file is your only concern than check out Apps like xender , Zapya they will server the purpose